ANT replacement
I wrote a c# windows application that:

calls ANT Retrieve to get a package of items (say, page layouts)
Edits the XML of those layouts
calls ANT deploy to push those changed layouts back into SF

Now that ANT is no longer supported, our security team is pushing for us to uninstall ANT.  So, I'm trying to figure out how to do the same thing with SF CLI.
I run:
sf project retrieve start --target-org sfclitest --target-metadata-dir C:\Temp\sfclitest\Retrieve\EnableLightning --manifest C:\Temp\sfclitest\Packages\EnableLightning\package.xml --unzip
and that retrieves the metadata just fine.  It unzips it and I can see all the pagelayouts etc.
When I run the following command to deploy it:
sf project deploy start --target-org sfclitest --manifest C:\Temp\sfclitest\Retrieve\EnableLightning\unpackaged\unpackaged\package.xml
I get the error below:
Error (InvalidProjectWorkspaceError): This directory does not contain a valid Salesforce DX project.
Note that this is ALL being done at the command line, not inside VS Code.  Is there a reason it will retrieve but not deploy?  How do I get it to deploy?
Or, is there an easy way to read/write directly to the metadata API from C#?  (I've been working on it doing straight api development and got it partially work but would be very open to a plug-in that opens up the metadata api if anyone knows of one)  I would prefer this to ANT or SFCLI but haven't been able to get it to fully work yet.

The SF CLI can work with metadata (i.e. "metadata api form") but is more geared towards using a different representation called "source form", which is generally easier to work with and I believe it (along with having an sfdx "project") is the way most of us are meant to use it. What exactly are you changing in the XML you're getting? There may be an easier way to do whatever it is you're doing here.

I suppose I should also mention, an sfdx project is just a directory structure and some configuration files. It's not tied to VSCode (or any other editor/ide, for that matter).

sf by default expects an sf project directory to work from. To deploy your metadata try using sf deploy metadata
In your case it would be something like sf deploy metadata --target-org sfclitest --metadata-dir=C:\Temp\sfclitest\Packages\EnableLightning\.
Run sf deploy metadata --help for more info about other options.
